Flask - Encrypt password before POST request
How can I encrypt my password before the POST request is made.
I am using BCrypt to encrypt my paswords. I know Bcrypt offers both a python solution and a JS version. Currently I do encrypt my passwords in the backend with:
@accounts_bp.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash("You are already logged in.", "info")
        return redirect(url_for("core.index"))
    
    
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, request.form["password"]):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for("core.index"))
        else:
            flash("Invalid email and/or password.", "danger")
            return render_template("accounts/login.html", form=form)
    return render_template("accounts/login.html", form=form)

But by doing it this way, the password can still by viewed:

I've tried importing bcrypt through bcrypts javascript CDN and then using it in a <script> tag but this did not work. Using:
<script>
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var password = document.querySelector("#password").value;
    var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
    document.querySelector("#password").value = hashedPassword;
    console.log(hashedPassword);
    this.submit();
  });
</script>

This resulted in a bcrypt not defined error.
how can we encrypt the password before the POST request is made?

Who can view the password this way? The user who just entered it in their browser. Assuming you're using HTTPS, nobody else will be able to intercept it. This is a non-issue (and no, there's no great solution to prevent this).

If you can grap the password, you would also be able to grap the hash. Basically by doing the hash in the frontend you have just made the hash the password.

the question is, why do you want to encrypt the password before sending it?
there's no real point in doing so for security as, whether you send the password in plaintext or encrypted can be used by an attacker to authenticate if intercepted. it's called a pass-the-hash attack

Couldn't I use something like an identity server?

i guess you could. But that doesn't change the fact that client side encryption really has no point.
You're already using bcrypt.check_password_hash in your backend to compare the hash of the password with what's stored in your database (comparing hash in datatabase to fresh hash of password). Using an identity server can also be done from your backend in (likely) a similar way. even worse: if you compare the encrypted value you send directly with the value in your database you're basically storing the passwords are plaintext.
